# visual studio code "launch json" on run, how to set debug console as default

Tags: installation, visual-studio-code

I went to user settings to set the debug console to default (when I try to debug now the default console is terminal.  I lose the small debug icons to skip, stop etc even when I manually select debug console). I am watching Python tutorials  using Vs Code and his default is debug.  How can I do this?

Secondly, when I try to run or debug, I am prompted to open LaunchJS, even if it is already open.  I attempted to run it using the debug selection "current file, integrated terminal" and also "Python: Attach".  Neither will work although the JSON file has these options.  I looked at some MS videos but I am not understanding the problem.
Any help is appreciated.   Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer at this link:  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial

I had not selectd a Python interpreter which establishes a python workspace.  Was just trying to run with debugger.  A simple program now runs.   My guess is that the Python tutorial I selected is too old to follow with this version of VS Code, since I am unfamiliar with any version of VS Code.
Thanks.